# select a paticular option of a dropdown AngulaJs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using AngularJs with ASP.NET MVC4. First I am generating a dropdown using razor syntax.

```
@Html.DropDownList("packageName", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.packageName, "No Data Available", new { ng_model = "subForm.packageName" })
```

Then I am repopulating my dropdown like this:

```
$('#packageName').empty();
$('#packageName').append($('<option />').val('').text('Select Package'));
$('#packageName').append($('<option />').val(1).text('Package 1'));
```

Now I am trying to set an option to be selected in my angular controller like this:

```
$scope.subForm.packageName = '1';
```

But this generate an invalid option. The error is like this:

```
<select ng-model="subForm.packageName" name="packageName" id="packageName" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <option value="? string:1 ?"></option>
    <option value="">Select Package</option>
    <option value="1">Package 1</option>
</select>
```

Why does the first option generate? Is there any solution of this?

Comment: The "Angular way" would be to use **[`ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)**.

Comment: Then go on and use it.

Comment: But what is the wrong in this way? I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Because Angular cannot read your mind yet. There is a new service planned for version 4.2 that will be able to read your mind and handle the DOM anyway you can think of (if you concentrate hard enough). If you are using an earlier version, you need to follow some conventions, so Angular knows what's going on.

Comment: If I don't repopulate the drop-down, it's possible to select an option by setting a particular value to the model. But the problem in the repopulating and then setting the model value. What might be the reason for that?

Comment: The reason could be that Angular checks the available options by reference and not by value. So, when you repopulate it, the references to the original objects will be lost. I am realy qurious: Why don't you use `ngOptions` ?

Answer (score 0):

Because of how the **[`select`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)** directive is implemented, it needs to know the available option-values in order to map a value of the asociated model to an option.
You can achieve what you want using **[`ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)**. It's quite easy:

```
<!-- In the VIEW: -->
<select id="packageName" ng-model="subForm.packageName"
        ng-options="packageName for packageName in packageNames">
    <option value="">Select Package</option>
</select>

/* In the CONTROLLER: */
$scope.packageNames = [...];

$scope.subForm = {
    packageName: $scope.packageNames[0]
};
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/G3KNu/)**.